# Talking to Prepar3d/Microsoft Flight Simulator from *nix

Tags: linux, unix, real-time, simulation

Is there a way to talk to Prepar3d/MSFS without using the SimConnect api so that I can do it from a *nix/any environment by doing something like opening a socket and talking XML?

Is there a build of SimConnect that can be used on *nix enviroments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old question, but may as well answer it.

Short answer is no. FSUIPC and the P3d API both run on Windows and are the only solutions I know of to communicate with the sim.

You could, however, write a wrapper for the API that receives UDP packets and inputs them to the sim. If you're familiar with socket programming this would be pretty simple, but you would have to make sure the Unix box was plugged directly to the PC with P3d, or you would end up with around to 100ms of latency or more (from the router).

Comment: Ian, thanks for the response. I have actually already done exactly as you have mentioned and used sockets to relay the information on.